# Implementing Custom Session State Store Provider in dotnet core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, session-state-provider

I was just planning to implement a custom session state provider for a distributed cache product in .net core but I could not find SessionStateStoreProviderBase and related classes in dotnet core. Can somebody tell me where to find them?

Comment: Hi, did you manage to implement this? could you lead me with some example on how to create and plug a custom session state store provider in .net core?

Comment: @acromm please check out the accepted answer. Sessions have changed in .Net Core so you need to implement them differently now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Session is very different in ASP.NET Core. It's designed around IDistributedCache and takes the implementation from DI.
https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/blob/rel/1.1.2/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions/IDistributedCache.cs

Answer (score 1):

This is more relevant now:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.session?view=aspnetcore-2.2

I believe you'll want to inject in your own ISessionStore for the SessionManager to pick up.
[SessionManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.session.sessionmiddleware.-ctor?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Session_SessionMiddleware__ctor_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_RequestDelegate_Microsoft_Extensions_Logging_ILoggerFactory_Microsoft_AspNetCore_DataProtection_IDataProtectionProvider_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Session_ISessionStore_Microsoft_Extensions_Options_IOptions_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Builder_SessionOptions__)

Comment: Warning: Apparently they have removed this totally in asp.net 6! (At least there's no documentation for it)